# Set user preference using local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858524/using-local-storage-to-set-a-class-for-user-preference) similar to this yesterday however it doesn't look like it's getting much interest, so I am going break it down.

Please see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2o70xgg/1/).

As you can see, I've got a 3 column layout of listings which can be toggled between two views:

**1) Default View**

**2) Alt View**

My aim is to use local storage to save a users preference - so if a user selects ALT VIEW for example, then when they go to the next page of listings, their preference (being ALT VIEW) is carried over to that page and throughout their entire session surfing my website.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $('.order a.layout').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      // do nothing if the clicked link is already active
      return;
    }

    $('.order a.layout').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');


    var clickid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.listings').fadeOut(240, function(){

      if(clickid == 'thumbnails-list') {
        $(this).addClass('alt');
        localStorage.setItem("viewmode", "alt");
      } 

      else {
        $(this).removeClass('alt');
        localStorage.setItem("viewmode", "default");
      }


      $('.listings').fadeIn(200);

    });

  });

});
```

Notice in the javascript above, I've created the **setItem**'s:

```
if(clickid == 'thumbnails-list') {
        $(this).addClass('alt');
        localStorage.setItem("viewmode", "alt");
      } 

else {
        $(this).removeClass('alt');
        localStorage.setItem("viewmode", "default");
      }
```

When I go on Chrome resources > local storage and test to see if these setItems are working, they are indeed.

My problem is that I am battling to do the **getItem** part which is doing my head in!

Comment: What's the question? There are no `.getItem()` calls in the code you posted. What's not working?

Comment: This should have been an edit to your original post.

Comment: A quick note regarding the duplicate ... there isn't any answer to that question nevermind a comment. @travis - I hear you but like I said no ones taking any interest in it - hence no responses or comments / answers etc

Comment: @user3364730 - Yes, but just edit it. Place your new information in there and it will get "bumped" (show up in the most recently active list) and that will garner more attention. If your edit makes the question answerable, then you will probably get an answer there as well. The goal should be to not only save people time by providing them with the information they need up front (people do want to solve problems here) but also to ensure that you are properly reproducing the problem you are encountering. If you accomplish that, your question will receive an answer. Please edit your original post

Comment: I never knew about the bumped situation - good to know! I shall do so, thanks